# C# ASP.NET - Dynamic Javascript variables

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'll try and keep things simple.

I'm adding simple html text boxes via Javascript dynamically with a simple html button and it's working great.

Here is my current code.

```
unction AddRow(tableId) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableId);

        var rowCount = (table.rows.length);
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        row.setAttribute('name', 'row[]');

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        element1.setAttribute('name', 'dName[]');
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        element2.setAttribute('name', 'nNights[]');
        cell2.appendChild(element2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        element3.setAttribute('name', 'rmvButton[]');
        element3.setAttribute('value', 'Remove Destination');
        element3.onclick = function () {
            var temp = this;
            temp = temp.parentNode.parentNode;

            table.deleteRow(temp.rowIndex);

        }

        cell3.appendChild(element3);
```

But when the user clicks submit from an ASP button I want to add the text from these dynamically created text fields to variables within a class for processing.

What is the most appropriate way to do this or have i dun goof'd with using Javascript dynamically creating these variables?

Thanks

Comment: The most appropriate way is to use servercode to create dynamic control which you want to access on serverside, even better, use web databound controls like `Repeater` or `GridView`.

Comment: why do you need to add this controls by javascript? could you add it with asp.net?

Comment: It's been around 5+ years since I've done any sort of programming like this so I'm still learning the API and framework.